# How can I change the height of a QListWidget to number of items it has in it?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a QListWidget and I have 4 items inside of it. How do I resize its height to the number of items that it has within it? Thank you in advance.

I have tried setting the sizeAdjustPolicy to AdjustToContents but it did not work, so I am not sure if I am doing something wrong.

Comment: can you post the code?

Comment: You could try calculating the size yourself every time an item is added or removed and then doing `setFixedHeight` or whatever it's called. That's if there isn't a better solution.